# Table size strange in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have 2 tables in SQL Server

**TbUrl**

- INDEX SPACE 12,531 MB
- ROW COUNT 247505
- DATA SPACE 1.965,891 MB

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [TbUrl](
    [IdUrl] [Int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdSupply] [Int] NOT NULL,
    [Uri] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [UrlCod] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [Int] NOT NULL,
    [InsertionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedIp] [varchar](15) NULL
```

**TbUrlDetail**

- INDEX SPACE 29,406 MB
- ROW COUNT 234209
- DATA SPACE 386,047 MB

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE .[TbUrlDetail](
    [IdUrlDetail] [Int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdUri] [Int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [Sku] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [MetaKeywords] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [MetaDescription] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Stock] [Bit] NOT NULL,
    [StarNumber] [Int] NOT NULL,
    [ReviewNumber] [Int] NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [UrlShort] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [ReleaseDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [InsertionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

The size of `TbUrl` is very large compared with `TbUrlDetail`

The layout (design) of table `TbUrl` is less compared with `TbUrlDetail` but the data space it's else.

I´ve done `SHRINK ON DATABASE` but the space of `TbUrl` doesn't reduce.

What might be happening? How do I decrease the space of this table?

Comment: shrinking a database is rarely a good idea

Comment: what columns is your clustered index defined on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a clustered index on the table? (If not you could be suffering from a lot of forward pointers - [ref](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/08/28/heaps-forwarding-pointers-alter-table-rebuild-and-non-clustered-indexes.aspx).) Have you made drastic changes to the data or the data types or added / dropped columns? (If you have then a lot of the space previously occupied may not be able to be re-used. [One ref](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2006/10/13/301.aspx) where changing a fixed-length col to variable does not reclaim space.)

In both cases you should be able to recover the wasted space by rebuilding the table (which will also rebuild all of the clustered indexes):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TblUrl REBUILD;
```

If you are on Enterprise Edition you can do this online:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TblUrl REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

Shrinking the entire database is not the magic answer here. And if there is no clustered index on this table, I strongly suggest you consider one *before* performing the rebuild.

Comment: THANKS! The I executed the command ALTER TABLE dbo.TblUrl REBUILD;
 and ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.TbUrl  REBUILD; The table have now DATA SPACE 38,773 MB

Answer (score 0):

With VARCHAR() fields, the amount of space actually taken does vary according to the amount of text put in those fields.

Could you perhaps have (on average) much shorter entries in one table than in the other?

Try

```
SELECT
  SUM(CAST(LENGTH(uri) + LENGTH(urlcod) AS BIGINT)) AS character_count
FROM
  TbUrl

SELECT
  SUM(CAST(LENGTH(title) + LENGTH(metakeywords) + LENGTH(metadescription) + LENGTH(Category) AS BIGINT)) AS character_count
FROM
  TbUrlDetail
```

Comment: Hi. The result is: 25452193 first query and 103720201 second query.